# Expect more than one result and send same string back

Tags: tcl, expect

In tcl, how can I expect two results and send the same string back? For instance,

```
expect A or B {send C}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a bit too simple for a more useful answer, but probably this is the best way:

```
expect -re {(A)|(B)} {send C}
```

It depends what "A" and "B" *really* are.

Answer (score 0):

For the *specific* case you mention, just repeat the body:

```
expect {
    A {send C}
    B {send C}
}
```

You can also write a regular expression (and, for the *single characters* you're looking for here, a glob pattern). However, if the `A`, `B` and `send C` really all stand for something more complicated, we have other options. For example, we can store the “real” body in a variable and use that.

```
set WhatToDoWhenFoundSomething {
    send C
}
expect {
   A {eval $WhatToDoWhenFoundSomething}
   B {eval $WhatToDoWhenFoundSomething}
}
```

This is actually a *good* use-case for `eval`. There's *some* repetition of code, but not much and it's easy to check for correctness. (Yes, it's just like the contents of that variable are each of those bodies.)

Comment: In this case, could also do `expect A $whatToDo B $whatToDo` -- without the surrounding braces.